# What is meant by verbose=10 on cross validate?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, verbose

I'm running a model with differential evolution to minimize the cross validate score I set verbose=10 in order to get an idea about how long that will take then I'm getting the messages below:

[image]

But I don't got any idea what that means. Why is remaining time increasing?

Comment: For the record: I think that the remaining time is "0.0s" in each case. The OP must have been mistaking something else for the remaining time.